# ARCore does not work in certain Android environments

Tags: arcore, depth

I am testing the aar file extracted with Unity in the Android environment.

The problem is that ARCore does not work on the Galaxy S22 Ultra device.

The way to implement this bug is to reboot the device and immediately run an app that uses ARCore, and it won't work.

You can implement this phenomenon with Google's ARCore Depth Lab app.

This problem can be solved by deleting and reinstalling GooglePlayARCore.

Why does this happen? Share your device specifications and suspicious logs.

```
2023-12-28 16:56:52.530 27839-28484 native                  com.example.hddfsampleproject        E  E0000 00:00:1703750212.530314   28484 motion_tracking_context.cc:2537] NOT_FOUND: Not able to find any depth measurements on feature measurements at timestamp 6826899695768
                                                                                                    === Source Location Trace: ===
                                                                                                    third_party/arcore/ar/perception/feature_track_ml_depth_provider_utils.cc:406
                                                                                                    third_party/arcore/ar/perception/feature_track_ml_depth_provider.cc:209
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I confirmed that ARCore's official documentation was updated this month and added session Config to configure DepthAPI. But it didn't solve the problem.

Written in the onCreate method of Activity.kt that runs AR content

```
mSession = Session(this)
val config = Config(mSession)
val isDepthSupported = mSession.isDepthModeSupported(Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC)
Log.d("@@isDepthSupported", isDepthSupported.toString())
if (isDepthSupported) {
    config.depthMode = Config.DepthMode.AUTOMATIC
}
mSession.configure(config)
```

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/developer-guide?hl=ko